# Fork(System call) - Number of process

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, system-calls

I'm new to system calls. Here is my question. If segment_A creates 'n' processes. How many number of processes in total are created by the following code.

```
fork();
segment_A
```

My guess is **'2n+2'** processes including the child and parent processes. Please shed some light on this. Its really confusing to understand fork system call.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would say `2n + 1`. Because the initial parent process itself is not created by that code.

Answer (score 2):

The parent process has already been created. `fork()` creates a *single* additional process, and each process then creates n processes.

Answer (score 2):

fork creates another process so after fork system call there will be two process and each of the process will create **"n" new** processes. So there will be 2(n+1) = 2n + 2 processes and 2n + 1 processes will be created by the code segment.